# Trying to save image to gallery

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and are a bit stuck trying to save a image to the gallery. I have followed the guidelines on https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics, and it works fine until I try to save the image to the gallery on the phone using *getExternalStoragePublicDirectory*.

When I use the getExternalFilesDir() all works, but when i try to use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory to get the picture to the gallery Ii got a NullPointerException. 
I have added the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest.

I have tried to read other posts about this, but havent found any soulutions to this problem.

Heres my code. If annyone culd help me finding out whats cousing the NullPointerException I would be thankful.

```
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}



private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

And heres my error in Logcat:

```
    08-02 20:04:12.920 17455-17455/com.example.android.fishlist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.fishlist, PID: 17455
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:282)
    at com.example.android.fishlist.NewCatch.galleryAddPic(NewCatch.java:192)
    at com.example.android.fishlist.NewCatch.access$200(NewCatch.java:45)
    at com.example.android.fishlist.NewCatch$2.onClick(NewCatch.java:101)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6891)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12651)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26083)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Are you asking the user for permission to access his files before?

Comment: I have added the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Do i have to have more permissions?

Comment: You'll want to ask the user for permission, check out this link for more info https://mobikul.com/getting-read-write-permission-external-storage-android/

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out.